# Convert Dynamic Layout into a BitMap in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

Issue is I have created Layout Dynamic and trying to make a BitMap out of it. For Existing Layout's this Code works perfectly.

```
    LinearLayout topOne = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramOne= new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    topOne.setLayoutParams(paramOne);
    topOne.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgreen));

    topOne.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    topOne.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = topOne.getDrawingCache();

    storeFile(bitmap);

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/premi" + "/" + "temp.jpg"));
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert the view to bitmap after view is drawn.
to do so you can post a runnable on the view and make a bitmap there.

```
topOne.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        topOne.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        topOne.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = topOne.getDrawingCache();
    }
});
```

Comment: I will go with this. However is there any way the View is never shown and you still are able to make a Bitmap out of it. This thing may be absurd but still is it possible.

Comment: i don't think its possible because if the view its not drawn then there is nothing to capture a bitmap out of it.